# Elastic search , And operator , Nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a document some thing like { "name": "abc", "age": "20", "attributes": [{ "city": "NEW YORK" }, { "city": "NEW JERSEY" } ] }

and i want a query to return NO record if i search with YORK JERSEY. i have used the "and" operator and it doesnt work since am searching on the same field and not multiple fields since york and jersey is present in both places , its giving me back 2 records , any thoughts ? and i also read about Nested fields but it requires reindexing of data , so any solution with out reindexing the data ?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: sorry , i thought i commented but looks like i didnt hit enter , thanks @Bhavya , it was helpful and i tried with your example and it worked. so is there any other work around other than not re indexing the data ?

Comment: thanks for your update . According to me I don't think there is any other way to achieve your use case apart from using nested query (b/c of the reason mentioned in my answer). And please don't forget to accept and upvote my answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the nested data type
> instead of the object data type.

Refer to this ES official document on [Arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) to get a detailed explanation, and please refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170932/10348758).

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**You have to reindex your data, after applying nested data type**

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "attributes":{
        "type":"nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "age": "20",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "city": "NEW YORK"
    },
    {
      "city": "NEW JERSEY"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "attributes.city": "YORK"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "attributes.city": "JERSEY"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

Returns no result

Comment: yup I re-indexed the data and it worked with above example, thanks again @Bhavya